# How to pass large amounts of text (with single quotes in text) to Angular Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button on my page

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-small-round" ng-show="row.Notes.length > 0" ng-click="showNotes({{row.Notes}})">View Notes</button>
```

I've got a couple issues, however.

First, the modal won't open with `row.Notes` as the parameter, because the (potentially large) text in `.Notes` can have single and double quotes in it, in addition to other strange characters (as it's potentially being copied and pasted from emails).

Second, even if I replace `row.Notes` with 'This is my text', the modal Opens, but displays nothing.

So, the code:

**controller.js**

In my main controller, the method displaying the ng-repeat table that these buttons are in has this method to call the modal:

```
    var notesScope= { item: {} };
    $scope.showNotes = function (Notes) {
        notesScope.item = { Notes: Notes };
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/content/notes.html',
            controller: 'NotesCtrl',
            windowClass: 'wide-modal-window',
            resolve: { childScope: function () { return notesScope; } }
        });
    };
```

The controller it calls is:

```
.controller('NotesCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, api, notificationService, childScope) {
    $scope.loaded = false;

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
})
```

The actual modal page itself is:

```
<button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn-danger btn btn-small-round"
        style="position: relative; margin: -12px -12px; float: right;"
        title="Click to Close (or click outside this panel)">
    <i class="icon-remove" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" title="Click to Close"></i>
</button>
<div>
    <div class="row-fluid" style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc;">
        <div class="span12 forceWordWrap" style="padding: 10px 0 0 10px;">
            <div ng-hide="Notes == null || Notes.length == 0">
                <strong>Comments from Submitter:</strong>
                <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 100px; padding-right: 10px; margin: 0;">
                    {{Notes}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When my modal does open, it's just a thin line with a close button... No notes, even with just 'This is my note' as the passed text.

So, what I need help on: I need to be able to open the modal, display the passed text, and most importantly, be able to pass the (potentially ugly) text to the modal, possibly escaping the single and double quotes in it so it doesn't break the click method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perceived issue with quotes shouldn't be an issue at all. It really only becomes a problem when manually writing variables with opening and closing quotes that may have escaping issues within the string. Once stored as variable it is not the same  thing

You have injected the `childScope` object into the modal controller, but you haven't bound it to that controller's scope.

To use `{{Notes}}` in the view you would need to do :

```
.controller('NotesCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, api, notificationService, childScope) {

     // create $scope.Notes
    $scope.Notes = childScope.item.Notes;

});
```

Also it is generally better not to replace whole objects, but rather just modify them

```
notesScope.item = { Notes: Notes };
```

Would be better as:

```
notesScope.item.Notes = Notes;
```

Comment: Rule One: Instantiate the stuff you are trying to use. Even after 20 years in this business, for some reason I forget that one all the time!

Thanks a ton! This was exactly the solution.